# Is it good style to answer the question and write the complete edited code as well?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Getting the last known value of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143955/getting-the-last-known-value-of-a-variable/61148800#61148800)*

I wonder if it is all right to post the complete code as answer. I found it hard to describe the solution without being very abstract. But posting the complete edited code also means the asking person doesn't have the chance to develop a solution on their own.

Is it good style answering with complete edited code?

Comment: Yep, if the code length isn't excessive, it's good to post a *full* solution. The objective of Q/A is mainly to provide direct solutions to problems, not to provide abstract guidance which may help someone come up with the solution on their own. We're more a coding reference site than a coding school, so "The precise implementation is left as an exercise for the reader" should not be something that comes up here (much, hopefully).

Comment: @CertainPerformance: the objective of the site is to provide **helpful** answers. While that metric is subjective, sometimes 'teaching to fish' makes for very helpful answers, while a full code dump can easily be very unhelpful.

Answer (score 8):

Answers should strive to be *helpful*. Generally speaking, the more an answer helps solve the stated problem, the more value is has. What is helpful, depends on the context.

For example, ask yourself if future visitors with the same issue can easily apply the same solution to their code, or will they need to extract your changes from it first? Or is this a *conceptual* problem, and would an explanation as to *why* the code needs to be changed a particular way be more useful?

If you feel the full code is more helpful, then by all means post it.

For questions like the one you link to, I do often add some more exposition to my answers. You could include a bulleted step-by-step explanation as to what happens, for example. Beginner programmers can't always picture what happens to variables in relationship to loops, for example.